# Gradlew Permission denied when using Jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, gradle, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When executing gradle-commands from the Jenkinsfile, an issue occurs which states that permission to use gradlew is denied.
I have Jenkins running on a docker container.

Running the `./gradlew clean build` command however works fine from my local project directory, but when executed from a Jenkinsfile, the following error is produced:
`/var/jenkins_home/workspace/<branch_name>@tmp/durable-0000abcd/script.sh.copy: 1: ./gradlew: Permission denied`

I tried different configurations within Jenkins and the Jenkinsfile itself without any success.
There also doesnt seem to be any solutions online (in particular with solving the occurring from the Jenkinsfile execution)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by declaring `sh 'chmod +x gradlew'` before the intended commands.
Here's an example:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'chmod +x gradlew'
                sh './gradlew clean build'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh './gradlew test'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying....'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In addition to resolving this same problem that shows up when **executing docker commands** from this Jenkins container (permissions denied, or not found), I've added `- /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker` as a volume in the docker-compose file

Example:

```
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    restart: always
    privileged: true
    user: root
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 50000:50000
    container_name: jenkins
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
volumes:
      jenkins_home:
```